# Find Formula for Curvature and Max and Min Values

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If $C$ is a smooth curve in 3-space parametrized by arc length, then then curvature $k(t)$ is defined as $$k(t)=\frac{||r'(t)\times r''(t)||}{||r'(t)||^3}$$ Let $C$ be the curve parametrized by $x=\cos t, y=\sin t, z=\cos t, 0\le t\le 2\pi$.

How do I find the formula for $k(t)$, the curvature. And, how do I find the max and min values of the radius of curvature for $C$?

Comment: Have you tried calculating? $r(t) = (x(t), y(t), z(t)) = (\cos t, \sin t, \cos t)$ and hence $r'(t) = \cdots, r''(t) = \cdots$, ...

Comment: We define the curvature for unit speed curves first. Then we prove that any curve admits a reparametrization by unit speed, and we define the curvature in terms of the previously defined curvature for the unit speed parametrization. You can look at John Oprea's book for more details. I'm browsing by the cellphone now (mobile app) so I can't stop to answer right now. If no one answer here in, say, $2$ hours, @ ping me here and I'll talk more about it.

Comment: @IvoTerek I didn't get any answers for this, can you please help here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression $$\kappa(t) = \frac{\|{\bf r}'(t)\times{\bf r}''(t)\|}{\|{\bf r}'(t)\|^3}$$ is actually good for curves with any parametrization, not only for unit speed curves (i.e., curves that are parametrized by arc-length). When I read the question earlier, in a bit of a hurry, I thought that you were asking about a deduction of said formula - as I mentioned in the comments, [John Oprea's Differential Geometry and Its Applications](https://books.google.com.br/books/about/Differential_Geometry_and_Its_Applicatio.html?id=xb48zk0wJfIC&redir_esc=y) is a good reference. That being said, you have: $$\begin{align} {\bf r}(t) &= (\cos t, \sin t, \cos t) \\ {\bf r}'(t) &= (-\sin t, \cos t, -\sin t) \\ {\bf r}''(t) &= (-\cos t, -\sin t, -\cos t) = -{\bf r}(t)\end{align}$$

Don't be afraid, plug everything in the expression for $\kappa(t)$ above. You don't have to think much, it is mechanical. Now, remember that if $\kappa(t)$ is the curvature, then $R(t) = 1/\kappa(t)$ is the radius of curvature. Once you find $\kappa(t)$, you automatically get $R(t)$.

And for finding max/min for $R(t)$, note that although we've been dealing with vectors so far, $R$ is a function that receives a real number $t$ and spits a real number $R(t)$. So you'll use what you have learned in single variable calculus - meaning: solve $R'(t_0) = 0$, then see the sign of $R''(t_0)$ (max.:  $<0$, min.: $>0$, saddle point:$=0$).

Just take it slowly and you can do it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am still having trouble

Comment: You have to be more specific. Add your work in the question as an edit. I can't help you more if I don't know where's the exact point that you're having trouble.

Comment: I plugged it all in and got k(t) as 1. I think that's wrong

Comment: Really? I actually think that you've got a neat answer, that makes sense. Sure, you can double check using Wolfram Alpha, but think: all that you're dealing with are sines and cosines. Also,  $x=z$, and looking at the projection on the plane $z=0$, you have a circle of radius $1$. So your curve is a "circle", but the height varies with the point. All this leads me to believing your result.

Comment: Can you please work it out to see if I am correct?

Comment: You can check the result here: http://m.wolframalpha.com/

Comment: And if you add there what you've done, I can take a look.